# Create a Meta-Thread for Drafts of Complex Edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Denizens of Math.SE may be familiar with a device there for drafting long, complex edits to Answers.

A thread of community wiki posts exists on Meta-Math.SE, [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers).  Users mark an existing Answer on that thread as Done when they are finished with their Edit, and subsequent users are then free to recycle that one.

Since SciComp.SE also uses MathJax formulas, I can easily see a similar need for such a mechanism here, esp. as the site matures.

The "rules of the road" established at Meta-Math.SE for sandboxing complex edits have been honed by experience, so I'd favor adopting them essentially without change.  I stuck the feature-request tag on this because it applies in spirit, and furthermore it seems to me that MathJax is not enabled on Meta-SciComp.SE (if so, that would require help from the powers-that-be).

Comment: It occurs to me that if MathJax is not enabled for Meta-SciComp.SE, then we might depart from the Math.SE pattern by putting the Sandbox thread in SciComp.SE proper (still as Community wiki and with thread reuse).  The advantage of putting it in Meta as "hidden" and not affecting front page display seems significant, but this might be a (hopefully temporary) workaround.

Comment: hardmath, it took us just 6.5 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I up-voted this a while ago, and it's probably worth answering explicitly. I think this idea is a good one to test out, and I look forward to the results!

Comment: I'll create such a thread, using the Math.SE metathread as a model.

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox was not created before as MathJax was not enabled on Computational Science SE Meta. [As of October 2019, it is no longer the case](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/553/20688).

**I have created the [Sandbox](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/565/20688).** Feel free to use it and test it.

I have taken the rules for the post from [Math SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/332683). For now, they are editable. But I may lock the contents at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems to be working well.