# Misleading link about MathJax help

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

The online help contains the following part at the [LaTeX section](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex): "Learn more: [MathJax help](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)."

Problem is, the link leads to a site about TeX, *not* MathJax. This is not really fortunate, as they're not equivalent; a link like [this](https://github.com/mathjax/) or [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would have been much more helpful here. (The reason why I used the word "misleading" is that it literally says "MathJax" help, yet the link leads to a TeX site.)

Answer (score 5):

Good catch!

I suggest using a [link to Meta Math SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It contains a lot of examples, allows to invoke editing (to grab the relevant MathJax template). This is also the page that is right now used at [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). I currently do not see, why we would want to create our own Meta post for that, as we don't have anything custom (as opposed to [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/79470)).

- I would also have to check if there are not issues in modifying that for a Beta site.

Comment: "I suggest using a link to Meta Math SE." That's just my second link under "this" :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Shog, this is now done.

We also noticed that you didn't have MathJax activated on Meta, so we've turned that on and updated the link in the meta help page to also link to the Mathematics guide to MathJax.