# Sandbox for Drafts and Complex edits

Tags: support, editing, mathjax

The sandbox on Computational Science SE Meta is intended for saving drafts of long and complex posts. It serves to localize prevent numerous front-page "bumps" of the [main Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) caused by edits to drafts of such posts. Also, it helps to guard against losing longly-composed posts due to system crashes.

When you are happy with your draft here, you may simply copy the code and paste it to the desired location.

## Proper Use of the Sandbox

1. **Do not post a new answer!**
2. **Do not delete answers!** Deleting seems like a reasonable option, but there are no "hard deletions" on Stack Exchange, and users with sufficient privileges will still see your supposedly deleted postings. Deleted answers will be undeleted and cleared for the use of others.
3. **Do look for an answer which indicates that it is free** and then edit it to your heart's content. If none appears available, take over the one that has been left unchanged the longest (which will appear at the bottom of the page if you order answers by "activity").
4. **Do not expect your draft to remain untouched for days.** There are no guarantees that your draft will be the latest revision if you return days later. While users will try not to step over others' toes, it may happen that an unfinished draft is edited out. Your draft will, however, still exist as a revision of the answer it was made in. If your drafting is expected to take place over a longer period of time, either

   - take note of the URL of the answer provided by clicking the share button, or
   - save a copy of your draft locally (or even "in the cloud").
5. **Do clear your draft** when you are finished. This includes removing all $\LaTeX$ from your answers. Replacing all code with a simple statement like

   `This answer is free for anyone to use`

   is sufficient.
6. **Do not create new such sandboxes**.

---

<sup>The text for this post is taken from [the analogous post in Math SE.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/332683)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This answer is available for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is available for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is available for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is available for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is available for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is available for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is available for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is available for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is available for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is available for anyone to use.